# WinSCP .NET assembly: How to download directories

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I wrote a application in C# that uses `System.IO.GetDirectoires()` and `System.IO.GetFiles()`

I now have to convert that to use SFTP. I have experience with `PutFiles` and `GetFiles` of WinSCP .NET assembly, but I cannot figure out how to get a list of directories. There is a `GetFiles` in the winscp.exe that I can use for the files but there is no way to get the directories as far as I can tell. Does anyone have a way to do this or is there a library that is easier to work with.

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
}
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the ftp server? You've got to show some code for us to help you.

Comment: Im using SFTP Session I edited my post sorry about the bad formatting

Comment: Gotcha. I added an extra tag to help this question get more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) of WinSCP .NET assembly **downloads both files and subfolders**.

---

Actually, you have to explicitly specify, when you do not want to download them.

See [How do I transfer (or synchronize) directory non-recursively?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_non_recursive)

---

If you want to list subfolders in a remote directory, use the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) with `EnumerationOptions.MatchDirectories` and filter the result set to the entries with the [`RemoteFileInfo.IsDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo):

```
IEnumerable<RemoteFileInfo> directories =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(path, null, EnumerationOptions.MatchDirectories).
        Where(file => file.IsDirectory);
```

But again, you do not need to do this to download the directories, the `Session.GetFiles` does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that

```
  // Connect
  session.Open(sessionOptions);

  RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = 

  session.ListDirectory("/");

  foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
  {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} with size {1}, permissions {2} and last modification at {3}", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FilePermissions, fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
  }
```

Also try

```
string dumpCommand = "ls";
session.ExecuteCommand(dumpCommand)
```